# TreePanel Nodes with filtered Children

Tags: javascript, extjs, treepanel

I have a TreePanel. When I filter the store of the TreePanel so that a node appears to be empty, the symbol to open the node is still there. I think it would be better if the symbol to open the folder disappeared if its content is not visible. Is there a solution for this?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `"expandable: false"` on the filtered and empty nodes (`children:[]`) and do the same thing when inserting new code.

Answer (score 0):

The icon is rendered if [the node's `isExpandable`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/src/NodeInterface.js.html#Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-isExpandable) function returns true. You can override that function to your needs.

Or maybe you want to override the `hasChildNodes` function to include a check whether the child nodes are filtered out or not.